# Opencart 3 direct image upload

Tags: file-upload, opencart-3

Is there any way to disable the standard Opencart Image manager and just choose images directly from computer?

Comment: Just use google... for example this one can be suitable... https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=19083&filter_search=image%20manager

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this plugin is not compatible with OC 3.

Comment: It is not a true. In the list: Compatibility3.0.0.0, 3.0.1.1, 3.0.1.2, 3.0.2.0, 3.1.0.0_b, 3.0.3.0, 3.0.3.1, 2.3.0.0, 2.3.0.1... So fully compatible.